# OpenGL cube not rendering properly

Tags: opengl

I have a problem when rendering cubes in OpenGL.I am drawing two cubes, one is a wire cube and is centered around the origin, while the other is offset from the origin and is solid. I have mapped some keys to rotate the objects by some degrees wrt to the origin, so the whole scene can rotate around the origin.

The problem is, when I render the scene, when the wire cube is supposed to be infront of the other solid cube, it does not display itself correctly.

[image]

In the image above, the colored cube is supposed to be behind the wire cube. i.e. the green wire cube should be on top.

Also the cube is not behaving properly.

[image]

After I rotate it a little bit around the x axis (current horizontal line).

The cube has missing faces and is not rendering correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

I have coded the following 
Note that rotateX,rotateY,rotateZ are mapped to keys, and are my global rotation variables.

```
//The Initialize function, called once:    
void Init(){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);               // Black Background
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                                 // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Depth Buffer Setup                       // Enables Depth Testing
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

void draw(){
    //The main draw function
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective(45, 640/480.0, .5, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //select the modelview matrix.
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluLookAt(0,0,5,
              0,0,0,
              0,1,0);    

    glRotatef(rotateX,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(rotateY,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(rotateZ,0,0,1);
    drawScene();  // this just draws the main axis lines,

    glutWireCube(1);  

    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-2,1,0);
    drawNiceCube();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The code for the drawNiceCube() is just using GL_QUADS, while the drawWireCube is built in in GLUT.

EDIT:
I have posted the full code at http://pastebin.com/p1kwPjEM, sorry if it is not well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datenwolf solved my problem. I quote him:

"@JonathanSimbahan: Parts of your code are redundant, but something is missing: You forgot to call Init(); after creating your GLUT window, hence depth testing and all the other state never get enabled. I for one suggest you don't use Init at all and move it's code into the drawing code, where it actually belongs."

Answer (score 4):

Did you also request a window with a depth buffer?

```
glutInitDisplayMode( ... | GLUT_DEPTH | ...);
```

#### Update:

Did you somewhere enable face culling?

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Comment: Yes, in the main function i used:
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

Comment: Hi, I did not use glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); so i really don't know if its being culled or what. thanks!

Comment: @JonathanSimbahan: Well, something messes up your depth sorting. Could you please post the full sourcecode of your program to pastebin.com so that I/we can test and maybe fix it?

Comment: @JonathanSimbahan: Parts of your code are redundant, but something is missing: You forgot to call `Init();` after creating your GLUT window, hence depth testing and all the other state never get enabled. I for one suggest you don't use Init at all and move it's code into the drawing code, where it actually belongs.

Comment: you my friend are a genius. I adore you for all your epicness. I'll put up a cult in your name.

Comment: the update helped, the fiart part of the answer seems unrelated (at least in what I'm working with)

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Either case may cause improper depth appearance, hence I mentioned both.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be cause of clockwise

> 10.090 How does face culling work? Why doesn't it use the surface normal?
>
> OpenGL face culling calculates the signed area of the filled primitive in window coordinate space. The signed area is positive when the window coordinates are in a counter-clockwise order and negative when clockwise. An app can use glFrontFace() to specify the ordering, counter-clockwise or clockwise, to be interpreted as a front-facing or back-facing primitive. An application can specify culling either front or back faces by calling glCullFace(). Finally, face culling must be enabled with a call to glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); .
>
> OpenGL uses your primitive's window space projection to determine face culling for two reasons. To create interesting lighting effects, it's often desirable to specify normals that aren't orthogonal to the surface being approximated. If these normals were used for face culling, it might cause some primitives to be culled erroneously. Also, a dot-product culling scheme could require a matrix inversion, which isn't always possible (i.e., in the case where the matrix is singular), whereas the signed area in DC space is always defined.
>
> However, some OpenGL implementations support the GL_EXT_ cull_vertex extension. If this extension is present, an application may specify a homogeneous eye position in object space. Vertices are flagged as culled, based on the dot product of the current normal with a vector from the vertex to the eye. If all vertices of a primitive are culled, the primitive isn't rendered. In many circumstances, using this extension

from [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/clipping.htm)

Also you can read [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml)